# In JSF on an ajax call, how do we create a HTML fragment using a different JSF page for rendering?

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a JSF page in which I have a `div` which acts as a popup window.

This popup is displayed when the user clicks on a certain `button` or `link`, until which it is hidden.

I would like to have another JSF page that provides the content for this div via an AJAX call.
I vaguely remember doing this using Struts Action and JSP fragment.

Is it possible to do this in JSF 2.0?

**ADDITIONAL DETAILS:**

My scenario is as follows:

1. I have a page that displays the details of employees as a summary table using the `dataTable` tag with a class `EmployeeInfo` as a backing bean that provides a `Collection` of `EmployeeBean`s. On this page I have a `radio` button as the first column in the `dataTable`. This page has a `div` that is hidden.
2. When the `radio` button is switch on and a certain button is clicked, over an `AJAX` call we need to hit the backing bean to get the details of the `EmployeeBean` that has been selected as above and populate the `div` based on this `AJAX` call.

The reason why I do not want to have a full submit on the first page and get the second page is, because I want to save the state of any changes that have been done on the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a  tag, you are able to show or hide content quite easily.  This is all rough code typed out quickly but in your bean, imagine you had the following:

```
public class MyBean {
  public boolean renderHidden = false;

  public void toggleHidden(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    renderHidden = !renderHidden;
  }
}
```

Then in your JSF page, you'd have a link to show hide your popup done as a ui:fragment:

```
<h:commandLink value="Click Me!">
  <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{myBean.toggleHidden}" render="hiddenarea" />
</h:commandLink>

<ui:fragment id="hiddenarea" rendered="#{myBean.renderHidden}">
  <div><!-- Content to show/hide here --></div>
</ui:fragment>
```

That ui:fragment could easily be in another JSF page that you include via ui:include if you need it to be.  The important bit is that the f:ajax take is what makes the AJAX call (on a click event in this case) and updates the specified element (hiddenarea).

Comment: Thanks @Lee!
However, my scenario is quite different.
Apologies for not including the details of the scenario when I posted the question. I have corrected the question above with additional details!